# Implementing references to objects of many classes in the constructor of a new class with parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, reference

How to correctly implement a class constructor:

```
class NewClass
{
public:
    NewClass(Class1 &Name1, Class2 &Name2 )
...
};
```

if the number of different classes Class1 and Class2 is significant?

For a small number of classes (Class1 and Class2) you can manually create all possible constructor overloads, and what if there are many such classes or an unknown number?

This code is used to implement the hydraulic network calculation. For example:

```
class Pipe
{
public:
    Pipe(Tank &pipeEnd1, Node &pipeEnd2 )
...
};
```

that is, a pipe class and two objects at its ends — a tank class and a connection class. But there are many possible variations, at least 5-6 different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use template

---

```
template<typename Class1, typename Class2>
class NewClass //: some_interface
{
public:
    NewClass(Class1 &Name1, Class2 &Name2 )
...
};
```

---

Or use `Class1` and `Class2` as interface

---

```
class Class1{};
class Class2{};
class Tank:public Class1{};
class Node:public Class2{};

class Pipe
{
public:
    Pipe(Class1 &Name1, Class2 &Name2 )
...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, the use of the template is not very convenient in other code constructs. I will try to implement Class1 and Class2 as interface.